# Randomly Sample a python Set without converting to list

Tags: python, random, set

## Question

I have spent a good amount of time reading various answers about getting a random sample in python, and `random.sample` seems to be the natural and most common choice, however I am attempting to sample from a python `set` object and was hoping to do it efficiently.

I am using a set due to the very nice and efficient set functionality in python (intersections, difference, etc.). For my purposes sets are a very efficient data structure, and lists are specifically not.  I have an algorithm situation where I have `N` elements in a set, and potentially need to take up to `N` subsamples of an arbitrary size for each sampling of the set.  Each subsampling of the set is not of the exact same set, and is defined by the properties of each element I must generate a subsample of.  Here is some vague code which demonstrates the complexity of the algorithm:

```
main_set = set(...) # Values sourced from elsewhere.
capacity = 20

for element in list:
    potential_values = main_set - element.set # Exclude values already in element
    sample_size = capacity - len(element.set) # Num needed to fill the set to capacity
    new_vals = sample(potential_values, sample_size) # <- insert sampling idea here

    element.set = element.set | new_vals # Union of sample and element set
```

From what I have gathered online and in some tests, `random.sample` appears to convert a `set` into a `list` object.  The size of `main_set - element.set`, `potential_values` is almost always much greater than the size of `element.set`, and so if potential_values must be transformed into a list on each sampling the algorithm will suffer performance immensely.

So does anyone have any advice or ideas on how to go about doing this efficiently with sets?  I appreciate any input on this matter, and before anyone jumps to the 'premature optimization' routine, I have a very good idea of the scale on which this is going to be executing and the difference between O(n) and O(n^2) is pretty substantial.

---

#### Clarification Edit:

I specifically do *not* care about the output of whatever `sample()`method provided.  The actual samples I am pulling from the `potential_values` are *small* compared to the size of `potential_values`.  Rather, all of the suggested `sample()` methods require a list-like input to work, meaning `potential_values` must be converted to an indexable type first, which is what I wanted to avoid.

Also I realize now that I brought up big-O notation in a really vague way and probably shouldn't have.  When I mean I wanted to avoid O(n^2), I really meant I wanted to avoid adding another O(n) operation inside the loop.  As it was pointed out to me `main_set - element.set` is of same time-complexity as `list(main_set)`, so it is already O(n^2).  Adding `list` conversion makes the whole algorithm more like O(2n^2), but none of that is really important.

Comment: While there are certainly use cases where it would be much more efficient to sample from a set directly instead of converting it to a list, this doesn't actually appear to be one of them. You're already getting O(N^2) performance simply due to the `main_set - element.set` operations. Depending on the sizes of `element.set`, you might get better performance by turning `main_set` into a list and doing rejection sampling.

Comment: Actually, since `len(element.set)` is at most `capacity`, which is 20, rejection sampling is probably the way to go.

Comment: Did you try `set(sample(potential_values, sample_size))`? Converting a list to set is `O(n)` and is very fast, so the only thing you pay extra is a temporary extra copy of the data.

Comment: @user2357112 I tested the timing on a rejection sampling by your suggestion, and found that if the source set is converted to a list for this phase of the algorithm, rejection sampling is actually _faster_ than random.sample.  Thats pretty cool, thanks for the idea!  It is probably the route I am going to take for this algorithm.  I am however curious to see if anyone has a way to directly sample a set in python.

Comment: @LieRyan `sample()` was just an arbitrary method for sampling, if it output a list, I would have to use `set()` to use the output correctly, however the question is about how to take a sample from a set directly, not get a set as the output.

Comment: @MylesGallagher: did you actually profile this? I highly doubt that the conversation to set is going to be your bottleneck.

Comment: If you're okay with mutating `element.set` instead of making a new set, you can simplify the rejection sampling down to `while len(element.set) < capacity: element.set.add(random.choice(main_list))`. As for sampling directly from a set, I'm afraid Python sets don't support the kind of access you'd need to do such a thing. You'd either need to write C code that digs into implementation details you're not supposed to touch to get at the set's backing array, or you'd need to write your own set type.

Comment: @user2357112 What you suggested is exactly what I put in the answer below, although if you want to write your own up that would be fine and I would probably accept it over mine.  After I did some research before this question, I sorta had a feeling doing some heavy modification would be needed for that.  At that point I might as well write the whole algorithm in C/C++.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LieRyan Read it again, taking a sample _from_ a `set` object.  The actual samples are small, never over 50 per sample (I used 20 as the max in my question).  The problem is, all algorithms want an indexable sequence type object, and sets are not that.  So I would have to convert the `potential_values` set (which is much larger than the samples) into a `list` and _then_ take a sample.

Comment: @MylesGallhager: both conversion set to list and list to set are O(n). There isn't any O(n^2) operations in your sample code, where's the O(n^2) operation that you're concerned about?

Comment: @LieRyan the O(n^2) wasn't referring to any particular line.  Rather I meant the algorithm as a whole would be adding an O(n) operation to each iteration which makes the whole iteration more like O(n^2).  Consider that the `list` of elements is about equal in size to the `potential_values` set, so having to convert `potential_values` to a `list`-O(n)-each iteration for n iterations gives me this complexity.  Unless of course I am completely not seeing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user2357112 suggested, here is a Rejection Sampling version of the code in my original question that efficiently samples n elements from the source set given that I am only sampling values from `main_set` that are not already in `elements.set`.

```
main_set = set(...) # Values sourced from elsewhere.
capacity = 20
listed_set = list(main_set) # initially convert set to list so we can sample
for element in list:
    while len(element.set) < capacity
        item = random.choice(listed_set)
        element.set.add(item) # Sets cannot contain duplicates, no conditional required
```

Although this doesn't answer the question of how to sample directly from a `set` in python, it does efficiently solve what my algorithm is attempting to do.  If after a while, no one comes up with either an idea to sample directly from a set or something more efficient than this, I will probably mark this as the answer.  Thanks for the idea @user2357112!

---

As @LieRyan pointed out, if `element.set` overlaps with `main_set` by a large percentage, this algorithm would fail to get a non-overlapping item from `random.choice()`.  Therefore if we are expecting a high overlap, such as perhaps 50%, then simply getting the unique items between the two sets with `main_set - element.set`, and converting that to a list will be much faster than this method.  Essentially this algorithm is for the case when `main_set` has very little overlap with `element.set` as a percentage of `main_set`.

Comment: Be careful with this because the worst case complexity of this method is infinity. If capacity is a significant proportion of main_set, this may take a very long time to finish.

Comment: @LieRyan Yeah I considered that this can potentially take a very long time, since the failures will happen very often if the overlap is a large percent.  Perhaps I should include a check to see `if len(main_set) >> capacity`, and use random.sample() fallback on the `set difference`.  Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `heapq.nlargest` which can take any iterable and provide it with a random key to pick, eg:

```
import random, heapq

sample = heapq.nlargest(sample_size, your_set, key=lambda L: random.random())
```

Note - this will give you a `list` object back, so you'll need to cater to convert it if necessary...

Comment: As Marius pointed out, this isn't really any faster than just using random.sample() suggesting that the set is being converted to a list (or something else) in `heapq` as well.  The goal is to get a random sample _efficiently_ from my set.  Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @MylesGallagher as pointed out on Marius' post... it really depends *really* understanding what you're trying to do. For instance, you could use the `set.union` method with a list, so the result doesn't need to be converted to a `set`. Also, `heapq.nlargest` doesn't convert its input to a `list`, it builds a list of size N based on the iterable provided.

Comment: As far as I know, building a list of size N based on the iterable provided is of the same time-complexity as converting to a list, sorry I should have been more specific.  It also seems that my question is confusing some people a bit.  I dont care about the `type` of the output sample, I was asking how one might take a random sample from a `set` object _without_ and sort of list building from its elements.

Comment: @Myles AFAIK - no in built way... maybe look at Cython to make something with a custom method (eg, inherit from set)... then fine tune the C code... compile it, and use as a custom `set` class

Comment: @qarma the function passed as the key is executed once for each element. It basically acts as a Decorate-Sort-Undecorate pattern. So while multiple comparisons are likely required to correctly sort the list, the `key` isn't re-computed each time. If one was to use the (deprecated) `cmp=` with a function that compared two random numbers, then yes - it's possible to end up infinitely swapping elements.

Comment: @qarma where N is the size of the required output (not the input). So think of it applying the key once to each value as it goes along producing a `(value, key)` pair or similar. Each time a new value is encountered, it'll have a key created, which is then used to decide whether it's suitable to fit in the desired size (if so, the heap drops one element, and inserts the new one).

Comment: @qarma you might want to read how [heapq](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) works - N obviously needs to be fully iterated over, but the heap stays size n with the property that the first key value is always at the front of the list. That makes it possible to just do a single comparison to swap an element if necessary. (So you'll have size n of (value, key) + 1 extra for each new N to be checked, but the comparison is only between the first element of the heap and the candidate...) - it's not a sorting operation in the traditional sense

Comment: [Previous comments removed, re: if key should be stable] It turns out that `heapq.nlargest` makes a temporary heapy array like `[(key(a1), 0, a1), ...]` and relies on native comparison from that point on. Thus `random.random()` is evaluated once per element. The space cost is extra array lenN and N tuples.

Answer (score 1):

A quick attempt at timing in IPython suggests that using `heapq.nlargest` isn't necessarily better than your existing method, adjust to the characteristics of your actual data as appropriate:

```
import random
import heapq

set_size = 100000
sample_size = 1000

def sample_heapq(your_set, sample_size):
    sample = heapq.nlargest(sample_size, your_set, key = lambda e: random.random())
    return sample

def sample_original(your_set, sample_size):
    sample = random.sample(your_set, sample_size)
    return sample

eg_set = set(range(sample_size))
```

Running these through `timeit`:

```
%timeit sample_heapq(eg_set, sample_size)
1000 loops, best of 3: 523 µs per loop

%timeit sample_original(eg_set, sample_size)
1000 loops, best of 3: 479 µs per loop
```

Comment: So it seems that all of these random sampling systems return `list` objects, probably because sets are less general use compared to lists.  Since these algorithms all seem to natively work with lists and return lists, I will have to convert my set to a list, and then the sample _back_ into a set afterwards.  So its even less efficient than I thought!  Perhaps its not super important though, since I am only wasting my time, rather than a clients time with a slow algorithm.

Comment: @MylesGallagher quite likely. Pretty much everything is designed to return N items - not N *unique* items (although - if the iterable/source is a `set` they will be unique - it's just stuff doesn't know that). Without knowing your problem further - you might also wish to look into just `list`'ing your `set` once off, shuffling it, then grouping by N elements at a time.... (eg: take the hit *once* only... instead of N*samples kind of thing)

Comment: @JonClements Yeah it is looking like a rejection sampling algorithm along with converting `main_set` to a `list` _before_ I start the looping is going to be my solution.  I am curious if anyone _does_ actually know how to sample directly from sets in python however.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your definition of **random**.

Just some elements, I don't care which:

```
[s.copy().pop() for i in range(count)]  # with replacement

copy = s.copy()
[copy.pop() for i in range(count)]  # without replacement
```

Elements with decent [pseudo-]random distribution:

```
copy = list(s)
random.sample(copy, count)
```

Repeatable pseudo-random distribution:

```
copy = sorted(s)
# random.seed(...)
random.sample(copy, count)
```

Repeatable pseudo-random, *hypothetically* with less runtime overhead:

```
heapq.nlargest(...)  # per Jon or Marius
```

Discussion:

- `set.pop()` already removes and returns arbitrary element, however it's quite predictable if object hash value is same in set, e.g. if it's same set of numbers every time, it may be acceptable if set is different each time
- `set.copy()` is `O(N)`
- `sorted();list.sort()` are `O(NlogN)` amortised, likely as set is randomised by hash
- `heapq.nlargest` could be `O(N)` per [Median of Medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians), Python implementation is a binary heap of constant size, making it `O(N*log(n))`, as N elements are filtered through a heap sieve of size n. Note that sing `key=` adds a notable linear overhead, thus `O(C*N*log(n))`, your domain will determine if `C*log(n) <?> logN`